# Best way to return large file as split zip files,Stream or Byte array WCF

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, wcf, stream

I have already return zip file stream to client as the following `MessageContract`:

```
[MessageContract]
public class ExportResult_C
{
    [MessageHeader]
    public PackedStudy_C[] PackedStudy
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [MessageBodyMember]
    public Stream Stream
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

I have decided to split it to zip parts when the file length is more than 500 MB.

**Scenario:**

1- User will call Export method which returns `ExportResult_C`

2- If requested file is greater than 500 MB split it to smaller part  that each section must have 200MB size.

3- If requested file is smaller than 500 MB return the `MessageContract` with one stream.

**Desc:**

For backward compatibility I have decided to change `ExportResult_C` to have two properties one named `Stream` which already designed for when file is smaller than 500 MB and the other one will be array of stream to hold all split zip with 200 MB of size.

**Question:**

1- Is that `MessageContract` can have another array prop of stream ?

2- If not, is it possible to change the `Stream` prop to array of Stream type ?

3- Or to implement mentioned scenario I have to change the contract completely or is there any better idea (in terms of throughput and backward-compatibility)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to share the result of my investigation and my solution to pass big file as stream to client consumer:

Question 1:

this is not possible to have `MessageBodyMember` دeither `Stream` or any other type, after running code you may got an Exception as following:

> In order to use Streams with the MessageContract programming model, the type yourMessageContract must have a single member with MessageBodyMember attribute and the member type must be Stream.

Question 2:

I changed the contract to have a prop member named `Stream` like what I was wanted, the `Streams` is array of stream:

```
 [MessageBodyMember]
    public Stream[] Streams 
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

my piece of code to split big file to parts of zip and make stream of each part into `Streams` like:

```
 ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(); 
        if (!Directory.Exists(zipRoot))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(zipRoot);
        zip.AddDirectory(packageSpec.FolderPath, zipRoot);
        zip.MaxOutputSegmentSize = 200 * 1024 * 1024; // 200 MB segments
        zip.Save(fileName); 
        ExportResult_C result = null;
        if (zip.NumberOfSegmentsForMostRecentSave > 1)
        { 
            result = new ExportResult_C()
            {
                PackedStudy = packed.ToArray(),
                Streams = new Stream[zip.NumberOfSegmentsForMostRecentSave] 
            };
            string[] zipFiles = Directory.GetFiles(zipRoot);
            foreach (string fileN in zipFiles)
            {
                Stream streamToAdd = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(fileN));
                result.Streams[zipFiles.ToList().IndexOf(fileN)] = streamToAdd;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            result = new ExportResult_C()
            {
                PackedStudy = packed.ToArray(),
                Streams = new Stream[1] { new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(fileName)) }
            };
        }
        return result;
```

At the compile time there is no any error when we have array of stream in `MessageBodyMember`, everything works fine until the service is passing array stream (`result` in code) to consumer at runtime, by the way I cross the Exception like :

> The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:29:59.9895560'.

Question 3:

To implement the mentioned scenario the `Contract` should not change for Backward-Compatibility so the contract have a message body stream like before:

```
  [MessageBodyMember]
public Stream Stream
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

but I am going to write stream of the zip part to end of `Stream` as one stream and in client-server will be read an split each stream as file

solution:

- 4 Byte for length number of each stream
- each stream content write after it's length number(after 4 byte)

at the end stream will be something like this

Stream = `Part1 len + part1 stream content + part2 len + part2 stream content + ....`

any comment and help around the answer would be truly appreciated.