# Memory allocation failed on sending Large byte[] using WCF in buffered mode

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding, c#-7.0, .net-4.6

I want to use `WCF` for transfer file between clients and server. I read many article that some people using `Stream` mode for this purpose. but for it's restrictions I decide to create service with buffered mode. For example consider this:

```
[OperationContract]
void UploadFile(Guid systemKey, string fileName, byte[] fileContent, string userName);
```

server web config:

```
...
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="7200"/>
</system.web>
....
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="myBasicBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
                                   maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
                                   closeTimeout="01:50:00" 
                                   openTimeout="01:50:00" 
                                   sendTimeout="01:50:00" 
                                   receiveTimeout="01:50:00" 
                                   messageEncoding="Mtom">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="8388608" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
....
<system.webServer>
   <security>
      <requestFiltering>
           <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295"/>
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
   <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

and client config:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="7200"/>
</system.web>
...
<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295"/>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicEndpoint"
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                 closeTimeout="01:50:00"
                 openTimeout="01:50:00"
                 sendTimeout="01:50:00"
                 receiveTimeout="01:50:00"
                 messageEncoding="Mtom">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="8388608" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
       </binding>
     </basicHttpBinding>
   </bindings>
   <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/fts.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicEndpoint" contract="ServiceReference1.Ifts" name="basicEndpoint"/>
   </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I can upload `400MB` file but when the size of file is `500MB` or above I got this error:

> System.InsufficientMemoryException
>     HResult=0x8013153D
>     Message=Failed to allocate a managed memory buffer of 1073741824 bytes. The amount of available memory may be low.
>     Source=mscorlib
>
> Inner Exception 1:
>   OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
>   \

I think I set values for `2GB` data but it fails on `500MB`.

Thanks

this code run locally and I have `16GB` RAM. Where is the problem and what value I should change to upload harge files?

Thanks

Comment: I think the problem is `BufferManager` that large objects are actually allocated by WCF and never disposed, so it causing memory leaks exception, it is better to use `streamed` mode.

Answer (score 2):

I remember I was working with a large file transfer, and I used `buffered` mode to transfer but was not the best solution because after a while I got some exception about memory leak or something related memory, I changed it to `transferMode="Streamed"` and everything worked fine, by the `buffered` mode it means that the entire content of a message is present in memory before it is sent or after it is received. While that is a good strategy for most scenarios, and necessary for messaging features such as digital signatures and reliable delivery, large messages could exhaust a system's resources.
take a look at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/large-data-and-streaming).

To avoid creating new buffers all the time WCF uses [BufferManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channels.buffermanager?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) to reuse buffers, up to the limit specified by `maxBufferPoolSize`,
`buffers` are expensive to create and destroy. You can use the [BufferManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channels.buffermanager?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) class to manage a buffer pool.

You can try increasing [`maxBufferPoolSize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channels.transportbindingelement.maxbufferpoolsize?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_ServiceModel_Channels_TransportBindingElement_MaxBufferPoolSize) to see if you can reduce memory usage. I strongly recommend do not increase it to max because I think buffers from the pool are never released until the app-domain get recycles. A period of high traffic could cause a lot of memory to be used and never released.

So I recommend you to use `streamed` mode to transfer large file.

To split files and works with large streams below links may help you:

[Multiple file in one Stream, custom stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40317625/multiple-file-in-one-stream-custom-stream)
[Best way to return large file as split zip files,Stream or Byte array WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40103387/best-way-to-return-large-file-as-split-zip-files-stream-or-byte-array-wcf)

it may also help you

[Multiple stream in one stream will not passed to client properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40423822/multiple-stream-in-one-stream-will-not-passed-to-client-properly)

Answer (score 1):

OutOfMemoryException says the process is using the maximum memory it is allowed to. Are you debugging the code whilst trying to upload this large file? Your IDE might be causing this problem.
Moreover, in my opinion, when uploading large files the best approach is to split the file into smaller buffers and re-create them in the server side.
Another approach can use FTP between the server and the client for handling the upload-download itself.

Comment: Thanks but the problem is in buffered mode `maxBufferSize` and `maxReceivedMessageSize` must be same and if I reduce the amount of `maxBufferSize` , the amount of `maxReceivedMessageSize` alose reduced

Comment: `OutOfMemoryException` just means that a block of contiguous memory cannot be allocated. It can be due to memory fragmentation.